# Finding and adding code into a module via a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create code in VBA that will search thru a module, find specific text, then add a string BEFORE that text in the same line. For example, every time it says "yo" in the module, I want it changed to say "Add This yo".

The code below successfully finds instances where it says "yo" in the module, but it doesn't add the text where I want it to. Instead, text is added at the very top of the module (not even inside a sub). How do I get this text to be added before "yo"?

```
Public Sub Edit()

Dim vb As VBComponent
Dim i As Long
Dim intFoundLine As Integer
Dim strSearchPhrase As String
Set vb = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module2")
strSearchPhrase = "yo"
intLinesNr = vb.CodeModule.CountOfLines

For i = 1 To intLinesNr
    If vb.CodeModule.Find(strSearchPhrase, i, 1, -1, -1) Then
        intFoundLine = i
        MsgBox "Found at " & intFoundLine
        vb.CodeModule.AddFromString ("Add This")
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `InsertLines` or `ReplaceLine` instead of `AddFromString`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the line with a the new text:

> ```
> vb.CodeModule.ReplaceLine i, "Add This" & vb.CodeModule.Lines(i, 1)
> ```

Based on Mathieu Guindon's answer, here is how I would handle all the instances of the search phrase:

```
Do While vb.CodeModule.Find(strSearchPhrase, i, 1, -1, -1)
    vb.CodeModule.ReplaceLine i, "Add This" & vb.CodeModule.Lines(i, 1)
    i = i + 1
Loop
'
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.

Comment: Note to readers: while this answer addresses OP's immediate concern with getting the results they're after, it does not address the blatant misuse of the VBIDE API. `i` has no business *existing*, and is being overwritten inside the loop by the `.Find` method call.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I can't believe that you would propose such genocide!!  `i` does have a place in the code just not in a `For Loop` ;-).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon interesting enough, exiting the `For Loop` if the search phrase was not found would make the `For Loop` quite efficient.

Comment: Ok, upon further examination, you are absolutely correct. My main issue is one of readability though - it's not immediately apparent that `i` is in fact being modified by `CodeModule.Find`, i.e. you call it with `i=1` and the `ReplaceLine` call is made with e.g. `i=37`. That makes `i = i + 1` prevent finding any second occurrence of the search string at `i`. I'd definitely use a much more explicit UDT approach, but this answer isn't wrong. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating all lines of a module seems a poor use of the `Find` method, which is capable of finding text anywhere in a module and takes `ByRef` arguments that, if the function returns `True`, will contain the exact location of the found text - that's a great use case for a user-defined `Type`:

```
Option Explicit
Private Type CodeStringLocation
    StartLine As Long
    EndLine As Long
    StartColumn As Long
    EndColumn As Long
End Type

Sub test()
    Dim module As CodeModule
    Set module = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule
    Dim foundAt As CodeStringLocation
    If module.Find("test", foundAt.StartLine, foundAt.StartColumn, foundAt.EndLine, foundAt.EndColumn) Then
        'L9C5-L9C9
        Debug.Print "L" & foundAt.StartLine & "C" & foundAt.StartColumn & "-L" & foundAt.EndLine & "C" & foundAt.EndColumn
    End If
End Sub
```

Now that you have the in-editor line number you want to rewrite, use `CodeModule.ReplaceLine` to rewrite it - for example by replacing the `Debug.Print` statement above with this:

```
Dim newLine As String
newLine = Replace(module.Lines(foundAt.StartLine, 1), "test", "Renamed")
module.ReplaceLine foundAt.StartLine, newLine
```

If you need to replace all occurrences of the search text in the module, simply run the search until `CodeModule.Find` returns `False` - like this:

```
Dim foundAt As CodeStringLocation
Do While module.Find("test", foundAt.StartLine, foundAt.StartColumn, foundAt.EndLine, foundAt.EndColumn)
    Dim newLine As String
    newLine = Replace(module.Lines(foundAt.StartLine, 1), "test", "Renamed")
    module.ReplaceLine foundAt.StartLine, newLine
Loop
```

Key point being that everything but the search text is an *output* parameter; by hard-coding any of these arguments, you lose the reference to the value they return. If you want to limit the search to a specific scope or range of lines, the right way to do it would be to configure the `foundAt` values before running the search.

```
Dim foundAt As CodeStringLocation
foundAt.StartLine = 10
Do While module.Find("test", foundAt.StartLine, foundAt.StartColumn, ...
```

That way you leverage the actual bidirectional nature of the arguments, without losing the reference to the output values - and without iterating up to 10K lines of code when you don't need to.

Note that this is purely text-based search and takes absolutely zero syntactical considerations: the API will not care if the search string is found in an identifier, a comment, a string literal, or a keyword.